# jQuery UI Datepicker hiding previous months

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to create 12 months jquery UI Datepicker with date range selection.
I'm using

```
numberOfMonths: [12,1],
```

which is working fine
Problem is when i try to select two dates between two months (March,15,2016 to April,15,2016) calendar wills start from April i cant edit previous month dates, i want to keep 12 months in every condition in short i need 12 months jquery datepicker which can select two dates. my code is

```
<div id="jrange" class="dates">
          <input type="text" id="startDate" size="10" placeholder="9 Mar" readonly>
          <span id="spaceDash">&#8211;</span>
          <input type="text" id="endDate" size="10" placeholder="10 Mar" readonly>
          <div></div>
        </div>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#jrange div").datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: [12,1],
  dateFormat: "MM dd",
  showMonthAfterYear: true,
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat"), $("#startDate").val());
    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat"), $("#endDate").val());
    return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];

  },
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat"), $("#startDate").val());

    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($(this).datepicker("option", "dateFormat"), $("#endDate").val());
    if (!date1 || date2) {
            $("#input1").val(dateText);
            $("#input2").val("");
            $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
        } else {
            $("#input2").val(dateText);
            $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So you mean you have multiple dates (Range of Months)? Do you have multiple `<input type="text" id="startDate" size="10" placeholder="9 Mar" readonly>` ?

Comment: yes,I've to select two dates only with two text fields, which will filled by calendar (range selection) start date and end date, Start date will fill first text filed and end date will fill 2nd text field, in my case its working fine till here, problem is if I want to edit start date i can't see that month which have starting date.